# Disabling view blocks cache

Tags: views, 8, blocks, caching

I have added a views block through my twig template file (`page.html.twig`) through Twig_tweaks. It looks like this `{{ drupal_view('view_name', 'block_name') }}`.

I would like to disable caching for that particular block, but changes to the `preprocess_views_view`, seem to have no effect. Any suggestions to disable caching for just this one views block?

Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
function hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  //Change the title of the specific block.
  $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```

Also note that this does not disable the page cache for anonymous users. If you need that too, then you also need:

> \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();